# Docker-compose // OCI runtime create failed // pthread_create failed

Tags: virtualization, vps, docker-compose, virtuozzo, fork

Recently I have rent a VPS as private playground and for learning docker.
I want to host a few webservices behind nginx-proxy together with
[docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/docker-letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion).

### Setup

The Server runs Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, Docker **version 19.03.6**, build 369ce74a3c, docker-compose **version 1.17.1**, build unknown.

4GB vRAM, 4vCores (The hardware runs on Intel Xeon)

### The Problem

As soon as I want to run more than 8 containers I get strage errors. There are a few different errors, and I can't especially say when which one of these appears:

- `OCI runtime create failed` e.g. when trying to start joomla as compose-project with mysql:

```
ERROR: for joomla_joomladb_1  Cannot start service joomladb: OCI runtime create failed:
unable to retrieve OCI runtime error (open /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v1.linux/moby/741c[...]6e3/log.json:
no such file or directory): fork/exec /usr/sbin/runc: resource temporarily unavailable: unknown
```

- `socket reset`

```
ERROR: for joomla_joomladb_1  Cannot start service joomladb: read unix @->@/containerd-shim/24f42b8[...]32fa1.sock:
read: connection reset by peer: unknown
```

- `pthread_create failed: Resource temporarily unavailable` I don't have any corresponding logs right now. I will post them here if the error occurs once more. But one line always seems to be `parent id not found`
- fork failed. When this error appears, I can't do anything anymore. See next point:

Additionally and in relation to that, sometimes I get some strange errors on my shell when typing any command.
When the server is in this state, I neither can su to root or reboot per command line. You can see me trying to type `sudo` in this picture: [Errors with any command. Even shutdown or reboot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXzNw.png)

### What I have tried

- I have seen [this report on Github](https://success.docker.com/article/how-to-reserve-resource-temporarily-unavailable-errors-due-to-tasksmax-setting) and a few others and the refer to a maximum task limit on the machine. I already set that to a higher volume as well as to `infinity` but all of that doesn't seem to help. (I once changed it in `/etc/systemd/system.conf` as well as per `systemctl edit docker.service`).

```
$ systemctl show --property=DefaultTasksMax
 DefaultTasksMax=4659
$ systemctl status docker
...
  Tasks: 52
...
```

- I installed exactly the same system on my laptop (except the virtualization software - the VPS runs on Virtuozzo, locally I used Quemu with virt-manager) - and all works as expected!
- The problems appear with any container I try to start. `hello-world`, an other compose project or an already built project...
- I contacted my hosting provider, also the referred to the above issue and said they wouldn't limit any usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now I found the problem: The hosting provider limits the number of tasks of the virtual machines. That technique is called *user beancounters*.

There is a file where you can inspect these limits that are set by **Virtuozzo** at `/proc/user_beancounters`

So, when you know that your VPS is hosted on Virtuozzo, you can `cat` this file or use of of the scripts from [here](https://wiki.openvz.org/Human_readable_user_beancounters) to read this ressource limits.

The file mainly describes 3 fields:

- **held**: the current usage of a resource
- **failcnt**: number of all refused resource allocations
- **barrier**/**limit**: a control parameter which generally defines the normal resource allocation border

(copied that from [here](https://virtuozzosupport.force.com/s/article/000013558))

If the displayed value in any field is insanely high, it means that these ressources aren't forced to a limit.

The crucial line in my case was `numprocs`. It tells the maximum number of tasks the machine is allowed to run. And as *processes in a docker container* also run on the *same kernel* as the VPS, the all count in.

So, the only solution here was to switch to another hoster, that doesn't use Virtuozzo (like that)!